# Use Python module on the runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime, pip

```
import os
import sys

#run get-pip.py
os.system("python get-pip.py")

#try to import pip
try:
    __import__('pip')
except ImportError:
    input('Could not install pip, please enter any key to quit this window.')
    sys.exit()

#install selenium
def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    install('selenium')
```

When I run this script I get:

`NameError: name 'pip' is not defined`

It's like `__import__('pip')` doesn't import pip, how can I make it import pip?

When I ran this code it installed pip fine, also the `try` didn't throw any exception. I get this error when it tries to install selenium, because pip doesn't get imported in the `try` for some reason I think.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `import pip`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to make sure whether pip is installed or not, if it isn't installed then it shouldn't try to install Selenium through pip.

Comment: But that has nothing to do with it. `import pip` would still raise ImportError if pip was not installed. The only reason to use `__import__()` is if you're trying to import something dynamically, which you're not.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, thanks alot that fixed it for me. Make it as an answer instead of a comment so I can mark it as selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the standard `import pip` unless you are trying to define the module to import dynamically. It will still raise ImportError if pip is not installed.